Xinput match device with special character in name
I've a touchscreen device attached to PC via USB, it's id is everchanging, since we don't have any other input devices pinned into it permanently, so I can't really map it over it's xinput ID, however I need to switch it's orientation.
How I've done that in past is with a simple command
xinput set-prop "Touchscreen" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1

However issue with this one is it's name:
Touch Touch Device ^MF40WH00U-CT-A1-6P

With an actual carriage return in the middle, which makes it seemingly impossible to match with xinput. Is there a way to circumvent it?

Include the carriage return as part of the argument. Using Bash syntax:
xinput set-prop $'Touch Touch Device \rF40WH00U-CT-A1-6P' --type=...

